# How to close sockets of a class from a non class

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, class, sockets

my script works like this:

```
# other part of code

class request(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
        try:
                socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                socket.connect((host), (port))
                socket.send(str.encode("test"))
            except:
                socket.close()

def loop():
    for x in range(5):
        request(x).start()

# other
# part
# of code

def startall():
    # some other code
    choice = input("command: ")
    if choice == "request":
        loop()
    elif choice == "stop":
        # ?
    # some other code

startall()
```

Is there a way to stop sending request if the input is "stop"? Note that this is just a sample, my script doesn't work like this. I put this code just to let you understand what is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop all requests at once you can modify your class as folows:

```
    class request(threading.Thread):
        REQUESTS_ALLOWED = True

    def run(self):
        while request.REQUESTS_ALLOWED:
           socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
           try:
               socket.connect((host), (port))
               socket.send(str.encode("test"))
           except:
               pass # Do what you need
           finally:
               socket.close()
```

Notice the alternation of closing socket. In your code the socket was closed when garbage collector destroyed your variable `socket`. With my alternation it's guaranteed that socket is closed with every iteration.

The `start` and `stop` events now can change the state of all `request` objects.

```
if choice == "request":
    request.REQUESTS_ALLOWED = True
    loop()         
elif choice == "stop":
    request.REQUESTS_ALLOWED = False
```

After setting `REQUESTS_ALLOWED` to `False` you should `join()` all running threads. It's just recommendation (and you don't have to do it) because normally when function returns it indicates that something is done. So after return from function `startall()` with `choice = "stop"` I would expect that all started threads are stopped.

Full code example:

```
import threading
import time

class Request(threading.Thread):
    REQUESTS_ALLOWED = True
    active_threads = set()

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def start(self):
        Request.active_threads.add(self) # Add thread to set for later use
        super().start()

    def run(self):
        while Request.REQUESTS_ALLOWED:
            print("Thread {} is alive.".format(self.name))
            time.sleep(1)
        print("Thread {} is done.".format(self.name))

def loop():
    for x in range(5):
        Request().start()

def startall(choice):
    if choice == "request":
        Request.REQUESTS_ALLOWED = True
        loop()
    elif choice == "stop":
        Request.REQUESTS_ALLOWED = False
        # Iterate through active threads and wait for them
        for thread in Request.active_threads:
            thread.join()
        Request.active_threads.clear()

startall("request")
time.sleep(3)
startall("stop")
```

The code was tested in Python 3.6.1

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. You said I should join all exited threads... How can I do? Is it needed to stop all the active requests/threads ?

Comment: @AllExJ I expanded the answer I  hope it will help.